# React: Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module index.js:1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i got the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module on index.js sometimes en index.css or bunfle.js

And i don't understand why? It not render my App and my div with id='root' stay empty.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Profile from "./components/Profile";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
    const buttonStyle =
        "uppercase mx-auto shadow bg-indigo-800 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:shadow-outline focus:outline-none text-white text-xs py-3 px-10 rounded my-4 ml-40";
    const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
    const [profil, setProfil] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${count}`)
            .then((reponse) => {
                console.log(reponse);
            });
        console.log('Hello')
    },[count]);
    return (
        <div className="h-[100vh] bg-slate-500">
            <button className={buttonStyle} onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
                Increment <strong>{count}</strong>
            </button>
            <button className={buttonStyle}>Change</button>
            <Profile />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

It seems that when I comment out the axios import and the useEffect function all display correctly

```
import React from "react";

export default function Profile() {
    const liStyle = "px-4 py-2 bg-white hover:bg-sky-100 hover:text-sky-900 border-b last:border-none border-gray-200 transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out"
    return (
        <div>
            <ul className="border border-gray-200 rounded overflow-hidden shadow-md">
                <li className={liStyle}><p className="text-4xl">User ID</p></li>
                <li className={liStyle}><strong>Nom:</strong></li>
                <li className={liStyle}><strong>Pseudo:</strong></li>
                <li className={liStyle}><strong>Email:</strong></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

ddd

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<App />);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i find the problem that come from axios.
I uninstalled the latest axios version which installs by default and installed an old one...

And all is working.